# How to add watermark to all files in folder?

Tags: c#

I am use method, in which openfiledialog and savefiledialog for second method for add  watermark on one picture, press button-call method
How to realize this for all pictures in folder?
I think,neccesary used folderbrowserdialog  like this:

```
AddWatermarkOnAllPictures_Click ()
{
folderbrowser.Dialog.ShowDialog();
{
}
}
```

I am right? May be, i must call method, which adds watermark and this methods  work  with ALL  pictures in folder?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "folderbrowser" is your FolderBrowserDialog

Iterate over the selected directory:

```
if (folderbrowser.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;

foreach(string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folderbrowser.SelectedPath))
{
 // Do something
}
```